# Text Outlines in iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm attempting to save a PDF converting the text to outlines (as required by the printer) but cannot seem to make it work. I found a reference to an example on iText's site, but they have changed their site since then and I can't seem to find it now. I am currently embedding the font and that works great, but have no idea how to flatten it so that the text is converted to outlines. I'm using iText 5.5.11 for Java.

Comment: If you give the old link then we can tell you where it is now. Actually we are currently trying to find all the broken links to our website and redirect them to the correct location.

Comment: The link points here: http://www.1t3xt.info/examples/browse/?page=example&id=191 but is referenced here: http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Converting-text-to-outlines-td2160228.html

Comment: Oh wow from 2008, that's like 5 or 6 website versions ago. :) That content is now on developers.itextpdf.com. Sorry I can't be more precise now, I am writing this on my phone.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I appreciate your help, but unfortunately that much I already figured out, but going through all the iText 5 examples I was unable to find any references that explain how to flatten a PDF to convert all text to outlines.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I was trying to figure out how to do this to eventually end up in other vector formats such as SVG.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using acrobat and .Net,
you can use acrobat iac to invoke javescript to save it to eps which is font outlined.

See JSObjectControlCS sample and javascript SaveAs Reference

[JSObjectControlCS](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/developer/acrobat/sdk/dc/sdkDC_v1_win.zip)

[SaveAs](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#rhtocid=_6_1_8_23_1_92&t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJS%2FDoc_methods.htm%23TOC_saveAs)

Below is my working sample

```
///fsharp codes
let saveToEPS src dest =
    let avDoc = new AcroAVDocClass()
    avDoc.Open(src,"") |> ignore
    let pdDoc = avDoc.GetPDDoc() :?> CAcroPDDoc
    let jsObj = pdDoc.GetJSObject()
    let t = jsObj.GetType()
    t.InvokeMember(
        "saveAs",
        BindingFlags.InvokeMethod ||| BindingFlags.Public ||| BindingFlags.Instance,
        null,
        jsObj,
        [|box dest; box "com.adobe.acrobat.eps"|]
    )
    |> ignore
```

**Update**:
before save to eps, we must add a [using convert fonts to outlines preflight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nOK0.png)

```
let convertToOutlinesScript = """ 
    var oProfile = Preflight.getProfileByName("Convert fonts to outlines");
    var oThermometer = app.thermometer;

    var myPreflightResult = this.preflight( oProfile, false, oThermometer);

    if( myPreflightResult.numErrors > 0 ) {
    console.println( "Preflight found " + myPreflightResult.numErrors + " Errors.");
    } """
t.InvokeMember(
    "setAction",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod ||| BindingFlags.Public ||| BindingFlags.Instance,
    null,
    jsObj,
    [|box "WillSave"; box convertToOutlinesScript|]
) |> ignore
```