# Analyze outlines of glyphs with iText 7 by means of serializing font

Tags: java, pdf, itext7, glyph

I need to analyze outlines of glyphs to check for intersections with other lines/shapes. Working with the glyph bounding box wouldn't be precise enough.  In essence, I'm looking for an equivalent to the PostScript operator sequence `charpath flattenpath`.

This doesn't seem to be possible with iText 7 alone.  `getGlyphOutline()` from `java.awt.font.GlyphVector` looks useful, if an iText `PdfFont` could be   "cast" to a `java.awt.Font`. A dirty solution would be external tools like FontForge, but is there a cleaner solution? Can I serialize a `PdfFont` to a valid ttf or Type 1 pfa font file stream that might be fed to `createFont()` from `java.awt.font`?

Comment: A comparable question has been asked for [converting text to to outlines with iText 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43101713/text-outlines-in-itext), but it hasn't been answered yet.

Comment: Unfortunately iText is not capable of precise outlines calculation. You would need another tool to do that

Comment: @AlexeySubach Thanks - that's a pity, but at least it helps me where not to look for a solution.

Comment: *Can I serialize a PdfFont to a valid ttf or Type 1 pfa font file stream that might be fed to createFont() from java.awt.font?* - a `PdfFont` can represent different types of fonts, not only ttf or type 1, furthermore PDF viewers usually accept incomplete font files, at least to a certain degree.

Comment: I guess then the only alternative to external tools would be parsing the glyph outlines from the font dictionaries. Or rely on the fonts being installed on the system and try to map the embedded names to them.